# Implementing Java Pivot table using Streams

Tags: java, java-8, pivot, java-stream, collectors

I have been struggling with this issue for a few days now.  I am trying to create Pivot functionality using Java Streams.  I only have to implement
SUM, COUNT, MAX, MIN, and AVERAGE.  For input I am given a Pivot Column Index, an array of pivot row indexes, and the value to calculate.

The catch is the data is in a List < List < Object>>, Where Object with either be String, Integer, or Double.  but I won't know until runtime.  And I have to return my results as List < List < Object>>.

I am having trouble with MAX/MIN (I am assuming that AVERAGE will be similar to MAX and MIN)

In order to pivot on multiple table values, I created a class to using my my second groupingBy

This will not compile, I am not sure what to Compare against, where to convert the object to int or if I even need to.  I would like to do this all with one stream, but I am not sure it is possible.  What am I doing wrong, or could I do it differently.  Thanks in advance.

```
package pivot.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PivotTest {

    List<List<Object>> rows = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();

    public PivotTest() throws Exception {

        rows.add(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{ "East", "Boy", "Tee", 10, 12.00}));
        rows.add(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{ "East", "Boy", "Golf", 15, 20.00}));
        rows.add(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{ "East", "Girl", "Tee", 8, 14.00}));
        rows.add(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{ "East", "Girl", "Golf", 20, 24.00}));
        rows.add(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{ "West", "Boy", "Tee", 5, 12.00}));
        rows.add(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{ "West", "Boy", "Golf", 12, 20.00}));
        rows.add(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{ "West", "Girl", "Tee", 15, 14.00}));
        rows.add(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{ "West", "Girl", "Golf", 10, 24.00}));

    }

    // Dynamic Max based upon Column, Value to sum, and an array of pivot rows
    public void MaxTable(int colIdx, int valueIdx, int... rowIdx) {

         Map<Object, Map<Object, Integer>> myList = newRows.stream().collect(
         Collectors.groupingBy(r -> ((List<Object>) r).get(colIdx),
         Collectors.groupingBy( r -> new PivotColumns(r, rowIdx),
         Collectors.collectingAndThen( Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(???)),
                r -> ((List<Object>) r).get(valueIdx)))));

         System.out.println("Dynamic MAX PIVOT"); System.out.println(myList);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            PivotTest p = new PivotTest();
            System.out.println("\n\nStreams PIVOT with index values inside a List\n");
            p.MaxTable(0, 3, new int[] { 2 });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class PivotColumns {

    ArrayList<Object> columns;

    public PivotColumns(
        List<Object> objs, int... pRows) {
        columns = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for (int i = 0; i < pRows.length; i++) {
            columns.add(objs.get(pRows[i]));
        }

    }

    public void addObject(Object obj) {
        columns.add(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((columns == null) ? 0 : columns.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PivotColumns other = (PivotColumns) obj;
        if (columns == null) {
            if (other.columns != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!columns.equals(other.columns))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for (Object obj : columns) {
            s += obj + ",";
        }

        return s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(','));
    }

}
```

Comment: That is a *huge* question. You might want to read about making questions *Minimal*. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve --- I didn't get far, but you said you have a `List` of objects, being either `String`, `Integer`, or `Double` and that you won't know until runtime, but then you go on to show a well-defined, fully typed `Row` class. So which is it, do you know or not?

Comment: Any particular reason it *has* to be streams?

Comment: No.  I am completely open to other solutions not involving streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As all possible values (`String`, `Integer`, `Double`) are known to be `Comparable`, you may perform an unchecked cast to the `Comparable` interface. Also don't forget to unpack the optional. Finally if I understand correctly, the result should be `Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>> myList`, not `Map<Object, Map<Object, Integer>> myList`, as your column may have non-integer values:

```
public void MaxTable(int colIdx, int valueIdx, int... rowIdx) {
     Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>> myList = newRows.stream().collect(
     Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.get(colIdx),
     Collectors.groupingBy( r -> new PivotColumns(r, rowIdx),
     Collectors.collectingAndThen( Collectors.maxBy(
         Comparator.comparing(r -> (Comparable<Object>)(((List<Object>) r).get(valueIdx)))),
         r -> r.get().get(valueIdx)))));

     System.out.println("Dynamic MAX PIVOT"); System.out.println(myList);
}
```

Results:

```
> p.MaxTable(0, 3, new int[] { 1 });
{West={Girl=15, Boy=12}, East={Girl=20, Boy=15}}

> p.MaxTable(0, 4, new int[] { 1 });
{West={Girl=24.0, Boy=20.0}, East={Girl=24.0, Boy=20.0}}
```

As you can see, you can handle both `Integer` and `Double` column. Even `String` can be handled (lexicographically max value will be selected).

For the averaging you may assume that your column values are numbers (`Number` class, either `Integer` or `Double`) and collect to `Double` (average of integers can be non-integer as well):

```
public void AverageTable(int colIdx, int valueIdx, int... rowIdx) {
    Map<Object, Map<Object, Double>> myList = newRows.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.get(colIdx), Collectors
                    .groupingBy(r -> new PivotColumns(r, rowIdx),
                            Collectors.averagingDouble(r -> ((Number) (r
                                    .get(valueIdx))).doubleValue()))));

    System.out.println("Dynamic AVG PIVOT"); System.out.println(myList);
}
```

Output:

```
> p.AverageTable(0, 3, new int[] { 1 });
{West={Girl=12.5, Boy=8.5}, East={Girl=14.0, Boy=12.5}}

> p.AverageTable(0, 4, new int[] { 1 });
{West={Girl=19.0, Boy=16.0}, East={Girl=19.0, Boy=16.0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

With input being a `List` of rows, each row being a `List` of columns, and column being a `String`, `Integer`, or `Double`, and not knowing which and how many columns to group by, and not knowing which and what type of column to aggregate, I'd suggest implementing your own aggregator.

Presumably, all rows have the same number of columns, and all values of a certain column will always be the same type (or `null`).

What you want it basically a Java implementation of a SQL group-by statement:

```sql
SELECT Column1, Column2, ...
     , SUM(Column5), MIN(Column5), MAX(Column5), COUNT(Column5)
     , SUM(Column6), MIN(Column6), MAX(Column6), COUNT(Column6)
     , ...
  FROM List<List<Object>>
 GROUP BY Column1, Column2, ...
```

You need 3 classes. The first is the `GroupBy` class, which must implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` as the combined equals/hashcode of the group-by columns: Column1, Column2, ...

The second class is the `Aggregator`, which is actually two classes implementing a common interface, one class for aggregating `Integer` and another for aggregating `Double`. The aggregator will be given a value (`Object`) and will accumulate the sum/min/max/count values.

The third class is the main class, what you call the `Pivot` class. It should be told about the desired grouping columns (with type), and the desired aggregation columns (with type), preferably using a [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). It can then be given the data, and will collect that data in a `HashMap<GroupBy, Aggregator>`, and then convert that result back to the format needed for the return value.

Example of how to invoke the Pivot class:

```
List<List<Object>> input = /*constructed elsewhere*/;

List<List<Object>> output = new Pivot()
     .addGroupByString(0) // Column1
     .addGroupByString(1) // Column2
     .addGroupByInteger(2) // Column3 a group by column can be be a number
     .addIntegerAggregation(4) // Column5
     .addDoubleAggregation(5) // Column6
     .process(input);
```

Or if you don't always want all aggregations, it could be:

```
     .addIntegerSum(4) // SUM(Column5)
     .addDoubleMin(5) // MIN(Column6)
     .addDoubleMax(5) // MAX(Column6)
```

With this, the implementation of `Pivot` can handle any number of group by columns and aggregated columns, and using it is very intuitive.